# onChange is not being triggered on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I could not find the right answer. I am not using the `select` tag.

My problem is that i have a JS code which goes something like this:

```
document.getElementById("roomnumber").value = '205';
```

I have a dynamic one it's just I put '205' there for this example because it's basically the same thing. and i have the input like so:

```
<input type="text" id="roomnumber" name="roomnumber" onChange="roomnumberValue();">
```

So far so good. So what I want is to change the value of some other input field when this value changes. So I used the `onChange` in the code given above.

And finally, here is the code for `roomnumberValue()`:

```
function roomnumberValue() {
    var blade1 = {!! json_encode($rooms_cat_1->toJson()) !!};
    var roomnumber = document.getElementById("roomnumber").value;
    if (blade1.indexOf(roomnumber) < 0) { // doesn't exist
        alert('doesnt exist!');
    } else { // does exist
        document.getElementById("btowelamt").value = "2";
    }
}
```

So this is simple right? I am using JSON `encode` to use a variable from Laravel blade engine to output an array from DB. And I am using `indexOf` to check if the value of the input field has any matching records on the given JSON array. That bit works fine. And it works on PC cross browser (at least Chrome and Firefox) as well when i input the number 205 in the input field manually. But when `document.getElementById("roomnumber").value = '205';` is used, it does not work. Also on mobile. Because as far as I am concerned, the field needs to be focused and unfocused? I want to be able to change the value of `document.getElementById("btowelamt").value = "2";` by using `document.getElementById("roomnumber").value = '205';` and not have to manually enter it. I don't want to `focus` or `keypress`. I want the JS to change the value and according to that, the other field value changes. I don't know how to approach with this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think events are triggered when the update is done in code rather than from the user interaction on screen.

Comment: There must be a solution? I have tried using the setInterval but what that does is, it fires the room number event every time and the `document.getElementById("btowelamt").value = "2";` changes. Say if i change that 2 to 1, and the interval re-fires the `document.getElementById("roomnumber").value = '205';` then that value 1 i changed goes back to 2. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I am using a QR Scanner to output the room number in to the input field. Here is the code where the QR Codes result is put inside of the input field:

```
document.getElementById("roomnumber").value = content;
```

So i called the `roomnumberValue()` as mentioned by @The SuperKat and @Matt Luccas Phaure Jensen right after the above code. I don't know why i didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why onChange is not working because, onChange is fired when the particular field looses focus then , if the value doesnt match the previous value only then that event is fired.

You can detect immidiate change by replacing onChange with onKeyUp

Comment: That's the thing. I am not using any keypress. I am using `document.getElementById("roomnumber").value = '205';` to change the fields value. There is no user interaction. i am using JS to change the field value! So how do i detect the field value change?

Comment: Why not then have the javascript that changes the value fire the reaction to the change right after?

Comment: Not sure what you meant. Sorry i am fairly new to JS. Do you mean to fire the `roomnumberValue()` event? Could you perhaps show an example

Comment: what he means is, at the point where you are changing the value of field from javascript, call `roomnumberValue()` there, that way you can catch the change

Comment: for example wherever you change the value of input field in your js, like, 

`document.getElementById("inputid").value = "somevalue";
// simply call the roomnumberValue() function after changing that value`